# Can they charge me late fees for payment that they didn’t receive because of their own fault

Tags: united-states, fees, rent, landlord, georgia

Back in Aug, my bank sent my rent check to my rental office. The address that the rent check was sent to was it has been the address since I have lived there since last year they’re in the same complex as I am just basically I can look at my window and see the front office.

The address has been the same since they opened now when you go to the website the website has three different addresses on it which they just added. There has only been the one address since day one. The rental office is in the same apartment area as we all are.

They did not notify any of us (tenants)about the address change so when my bank sent the payment, they sent it to the address that was the address at that time.

I have paid rent since then and they’ve accepted payment since November, but have certainly been charging me late fees on top of the amount owed, even though I provided them proof that the bank sent it to their address.

Are they allowed to try to evict me because of that even tho they’ve been taking payment since Aug and can they continuously charge me late fees because they changed the address and didn’t notify anybody.

I live in Georgia

Comment: Does your lease specify what address you should mail your rent check to?  Is that the address you set your bank up to use?

Answer (score 1):

In Georgia, they cannot initiate eviction if they've agreed to accept rent from you. However they may still charge you fees if they feel you've violated the contract.

If they do file an eviction against you, you should be properly served and given a chance to respond. In your response you'll write the details of the situation for the judge to consider.

Re notifications - you need to read the lease to see what would their obligation on notifications be. It may be something like "we post a note on the door" or may be something like "we send a certified mail to an address XYZ", and you'll need to show that that is what they *haven't* done to demand the fees removed.

If they continue racking fees up despite accepting your payment and confirming the new address, you may want to consult with an attorney. See here for the [Georgia legal aid contact information and details](https://www.georgialegalaid.org/resource/learn-about-eviction-in-georgia-1). Here are the [resources for Fulton county](https://www.magistratefulton.org/165/Landlord-Tenant-Dispossessory) (Atlanta).